# How do I save an uploaded file as raw binary data in python

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to store files obtained from a web page. I've tried databases, but they aren't working for me. So I decided to try and save the file as raw binary data in python (Probably in an array).

I intend to pull out the data and display it in the same manner as it is submitted. Can I know if this is doable and if yes, how do I do it.

Below is the html file to obtain the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>FoodSaver</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>File Input</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputFile">File Input</label>
        <input type="file" name="inputFile">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The python file below should show the above html file and upon submission, it will print out the data obtained as a string.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['inputFile']
    print(str(file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What do you want to print? the content of the file or the file as string?

Comment: From your code I can infer that you are trying to typecast a filestorage format. And thats not correct and you may not want to do it. Have you tried **file.save(path, filename))**.